# #1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with several "categories", called `collection` (e.g. A, B, C, ...).

I would like to create a SQL query to select N records by each `collection`.

For example:

I would like to select 2 records by each `collection`.

Table `stac_item`:

```
id | collection | name
1  | A          | name_01
2  | A          | name_02
3  | A          | name_03
4  | B          | name_04
5  | B          | name_05
6  | B          | name_06
7  | B          | name_07
8  | C          | name_08
9  | C          | name_09
```

I expect the following result:

```
id | collection | name
1  | A          | name_01
2  | A          | name_02
4  | B          | name_04
5  | B          | name_05
8  | C          | name_08
9  | C          | name_09
```

I have created the SQL query below, but MariaDB gives the following error message:

`#1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stac_item a1
WHERE a1.collection IN
(
    SELECT a2.collection 
    FROM stac_item a2 
    WHERE a1.collection = a2.collection 
    LIMIT 2
)
```

Would anyone know an alternative that I could use? I have searched on the internet, but I was not able to find a solution.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I use the following [MariaDB Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb): `mariadb:10.5.3`

Comment: Which is "this version of MariaDB"?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER in CTE.

Comment: @mustaccio I use the following [MariaDB Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb): `mariadb:10.5.3`. @Akina I have never used these options before. I will look for them. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the window function [`row_number`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/), like so:

```
select id, collection, name from (
  select id, collection, name, 
  row_number() over (partition by collection order by id) rn
  from stac_item 
) t
where rn < 3
order by id
```

Comment: Sir, your query worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT w.* 
      , IF(@coll = @coll:=w.collection, @cnt:=@cnt+1, @cnt:=1) AS counter
   FROM stac_item AS w
  WHERE @cnt := 1
  ORDER BY w.collection ASC, w.name ASC
 HAVING counter < 3
```

This query can be very slow on a huge tables

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please, could you provide a short explanation of the query? I tried to execute your query, but MariaDB returned the following error message: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING counter < 3' at line 6`